# Impulse calculation

Tags: matlab

I have written this MATLAB function to plot the impulse response. But it doesn't give me the desired output (impulse function). I am new to MATLAB. Can anyone tell me where i went wrong with the code?

```
   function [] = impulse() 
   t=-10:1:10;
   x=zeros(length(t));
   for(i=-10:1:10)
     if(i==0)
       x=1;
     end
     plot(t,x);
     xlabel('t');
     ylabel('delta(t)');
     title('impulse response');
     axis([-10,10,-1,2])
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is no end statement for the loop.There should be an end statement after the end for the if statement.Also x=1 inside the if condition converts the x vector into a vector of length 1.It should be changed as x(i+11)=1.Then the code works to give you a plot of a delta function

Answer (score -1):

If you write `zeros(length(t))` you are creating a matrix with `length(t)` rows and `length(t)` columns. Instead, you should write `zeros(1, length(t))` in order to have an array. Also you don't need a for loop. Try this:

```
   t = -10:1:10;
   x = zeros(1, length(t));
   x(t==0) = 1;
```

However, an `end` is missing in your code, because both `if` and `for` need it, and you should write `x(i)` in order to insert `1` in that specific position.

Comment: Any chance to elaborate, instead of simply pasting the code?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I edited my answer.